# How can loops be used in constexpr functions in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, c++17

I have a loop inside a `constexpr` function, which compiles in Xcode but not in Qt Console.

I am using C++17 in Qt Creator 4.9.0 - Qt 5.12.2 (Clang 10.0 (Apple), 64 bit), and Xcode 10.1 with compiler flag `-std=c++17`.

In the Qt Console .pro file, I have tried:

- setting `CONFIG += c++17` and/or `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17`;
- replacing the lambda with a named function;
- replacing the `do`-`while` loop with a `for` loop, a `while` loop and a `goto` loop.

As an example, in Qt, for the program below I get an error:

> "error: statement not allowed in constexpr function"

with "`do`" underlined.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>

constexpr auto least_significant_bit(uint64_t bits) {
    constexpr uint64_t magic = 0x07edd5e59a4e28c2ULL;
    constexpr auto lsb_map = []() constexpr {
        std::array<int, 64> result {0};
        uint64_t bit = 1; int i = 0;
        do { // problem
            result [bit * magic >> 58] = i;
            i++;
            bit <<= 1;
        } while(bit);
        return result;
    }();
    return lsb_map[(bits & -bits) * magic >> 58];
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::cout << least_significant_bit(0b10000100010000ULL) << std::endl;
}
```

What do I need to do to make constexpr functions containing loops compile in Qt? The expected output is 4.

Here is the build output:

```
02:09:09: Running steps for project test...
02:09:09: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
02:09:09: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" -j8
/Users/freddiewoodruff/Qt/5.11.1/clang_64/bin/qmake -o Makefile ../test/test.pro -spec macx-clang CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=x86_64 CONFIG+=qml_debug
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang++ -c -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++17 -g -std=gnu++11  -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I../test -I. -I/Users/freddiewoodruff/Qt/5.11.1/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -o main.o ../test/main.cpp
../test/main.cpp:5:11: error: 'auto' return without trailing return type; deduced return types are a C++14 extension
constexpr auto least_significant_bit(uint64_t bits) {
          ^
../test/main.cpp:7:35: warning: 'constexpr' on lambda expressions is a C++17 extension [-Wc++17-extensions]
    constexpr auto lsb_map = []() constexpr {
                                  ^
../test/main.cpp:8:29: warning: variable declaration in a constexpr function is a C++14 extension [-Wc++14-extensions]
        std::array<int, 64> result {0};
                            ^
../test/main.cpp:9:18: warning: variable declaration in a constexpr function is a C++14 extension [-Wc++14-extensions]
        uint64_t bit = 1; int i = 0;
                 ^
../test/main.cpp:9:31: warning: variable declaration in a constexpr function is a C++14 extension [-Wc++14-extensions]
        uint64_t bit = 1; int i = 0;
                              ^
../test/main.cpp:10:9: error: statement not allowed in constexpr function
        do { // problem
        ^
../test/main.cpp:20:14: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
             ^
../test/main.cpp:20:33: warning: unused parameter 'argv' [-Wunused-parameter]
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
                                ^
6 warnings and 2 errors generated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
02:09:10: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project test (kit: Desktop Qt 5.11.1 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
02:09:10: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

and here is the .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += -std=c++17
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
```

Comment: Well `goto` doesn't work since it's not allowed in a [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) function.

Comment: As for the error you get, can you please edit your question to include a copy-paste of the *full* and *complete* build output? Including any possible informational notes.

Comment: With Qt 5.12.2, QtCreator 4.8.2, QMake 3.1 in Linux it works correctly. In my case it generates: `g++ -c -pipe -std=c++17 -g -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I../55754970 -I. -I/usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../55754970/main.cpp` instead, in yours I see `-std=c++17 -g -std=gnu++11` which may be a qmake bug from a lastest version or referring to your OS I recommend reporting it

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this bit in your command: `-std=gnu++11`.

You're compiling for C++11, and in C++11 `constexpr` functions were limited to a single statement - no loops.

switch that bit to `-std=c++14` or `-std=c++17` and things will get better.

[Later: Even though you say you're using C++17, the build log shows `-std=gnu++11` as well]

Comment: How do I use `-std=c++17`? Do I disable `-std=gnu++11` and if so how?

Comment: You've got two `-std=`s in your command line. I don't know the QT build system, so I can't tell you how to get rid of one of them - but I'm pretty sure that's what you need to do.

Comment: Try to replace the configuration instead of extend it. `CONFIG = -std=c++17` instead of `CONFIG += -std=c++17` . But take care about all the other configuration flags. See your log.